# How do I save data on app

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework to make an Android app. Problem is, I don't know how people are going to save their work because it is all going to get deleted when the app is closed. I need to know how to keep all the data from getting deleted so the user won't have to restart all over in what they were doing.

I am new to app and web programming and such, so sorry if this was a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is using ready-made service like Firebase, with Ionic service $firebaseArray.

If you use this, you don't need to bother yourself with developing database at your own. Also, Firebase API is very easy to understand.

see: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Ionic, but generally you can use an external database to store any data you'd need when developing your app. Then you can effectively interact with this data/ database via your API from within your app.

See here for reference:
http://blog.ionic.io/creating-an-ionic-app-with-mysql-and-backand/

The alternative is to store your data locally:
http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/

It depends how much data you will be storing/ what you plan to do with it, but you should be able to implement one (or both) of these methods to achieve what you need.